# Hide/Show video when button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a BMI Calculator, and to play a video that correlates with the entered BMI. I can't figure out how to do it though. I want the video to only appear when the calculate button is pressed.
My script to show the results so far.
`<!-- SCRIPT -->

```
function BMI() {
    var h=document.getElementById('h').value;
    var w=document.getElementById('w').value;
    var bmi=w/(h/100*h/100);
    var bmio=(bmi.toFixed(2));
    if (bmio < 18.5)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You're Underweight, Your BMI is    " + bmio;
    }
    if (bmio > 18.4 && bmio < 25 )
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You're Healthy, Your BMI is " + bmio ;
    }
    if (bmio > 24.9 && bmio < 30 )
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You're Overweight, Your BMI is " + bmio ;
    }
    if (bmio > 30 )
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You're Obese, Your BMI is " + bmio ;
    }
}
```

`
I don't know where to start, I'm a beginner to this. Sorry if I haven't clarified well enough.

Comment: Add `.show()` / `.hide()` to the element depending on the value of the `if`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can add an empty video-tag to the html and set the src `(video element).src = link` with JS according to the results. Then you can start the video with `(video element).play()`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display of the element to none and change it when the button is pressed.

```
document.getElementById(/*id of the element */).style.display="none";
document.getElementById(/*id of the element */).style.display="/*display*/";
```